# Rails active admin implement my action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to introduce to my method some action (not as in activeadmin gem like view,edit etc), but my own, like upload file and do something in controller method, but how to do this, also i need link in activeadmin like "mymethod". Are any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try writing,

```
 controller do 

  def method_name
  //some stuff
  end

 end
```

in your active admin resource file in app/admin/some_resource_name.rb

Comment: hm no... i need all (cocntroller + view)

Answer (score -1):

if u want to add controller action for the active_admin, checkout  https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Add-custom-actions-and-buttons

Comment: hm no... i need all (controller + view)

Comment: can u explain the problem in more details?

Comment: i need in my adctiveadmin do such punkt as for example for post model, but not only index,edit etc actions, but add my action, and view for it

Comment: that link refers to a new wiki page; no content

Comment: @wkhatch this answer is 3 yrs old. the link might have changed.